# DataType varchar is not supported||Azure Databricks

Tags: sql

I'm trying to cast my data to varchar for a dynamic sequence, starting with `Emp`  in my 'Azure 10.4 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12)' so I wrote following query

```
SELECT ID,
       'Emp' + CAST(Row_Number() Over(Partition by ID ORDER BY ID) As VARCHAR) as col,
FROM EMPMaster
```

But I'm getting error message saying that

> ParseException:
>  DataType varchar is not supported.(line 1, pos
> 112)

Can you please help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Do you perhaps need to specify length? E.g. `VARCHAR(11)`.

Comment: Try with STRING